# Failed to authenticate for service: calendar

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, urlfetch

I'm trying to create a web app that allows the user to add themself as an owner to a calendar. I'm trying to insert a new rule into the calendar's ACL, but I'm having trouble getting permission to use access the Calendar API.

After I authorized the script to run through the dialog that popped up, I got the following error message: "Failed to authenticate for service: calendar."

What am I doing incorrectly?

```
  function insertRule() {
     ScriptApp.invalidateAuth();
     var calId = MY_CAL_ID;
     var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
     var API_KEY = MY_API_KEY; 

     var apiName = 'calendar';
     var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar';
     var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_(apiName, scope);

     fetchArgs.method = "POST";

     var payload = 
     {
       "role" : "owner",
       "scope" : 
       { 
         "type" : "user",
         "value" : userEmail
       }
     };

     fetchArgs.payload = payload;

     var base = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/'; 
     var url = base + calId + '/acl?key=' + API_KEY;

     var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs).getContentText();
```

}

```
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem.
I've found the link below, but the client would be scripts.google.com? Hopefully, it will get us pointed in the right direction.

http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.ca/2011/12/calendar-api-v3-2-legged-oauth-java.html